# Aggregating Output Based on Corresponding Values in a 3rd Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am need of help to solve this problem.

There are three tables that are being referenced to get the final output but the output is needed in a very specific way.

The ***first*** table has **QID** which are of questionnaires distributed to students in corresponding **ClassID**.
Each ClassID corresponds to a section that can have multiple students responding to questionnaires.

The ***second*** table has **RID** which is the identifier for a response received for a questionnaire. (I was using this to get a count of the RIDs grouped by QIDs, this gives me total responses - referenced as TotalR in the output table, to a QID/ClassID)

The ***third*** table tells us which classes, **ClassID**, are cross sections **CrossID**, meaning EDU 103 is same as EDE 101 so the responses for EDU 103 and EDE 101 should be summed when counting. (this is what I where I am stuck as I am not sure how to leverage this table.)

The final output should show all QuestionaireIDs and their summation of responses. This table lists all of the QIDs with their corresponding ClassIDs. The TotalR, however, is the total of the RIDs where ClassID = ClassID OR ClassID = CrossID.

**Table 1 - Questionnaire**

| QID | ClassID |
| --- | --- |
| 21 | CMP 101 |
| 22 | EDU 103 |
| 23 | EDE 101 |

**Table 2 - Responses**

| RID | QID |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | 21 |
| 13 | 22 |
| 14 | 23 |
| 15 | 21 |
| 16 | 23 |

**Table 3 - Cross Courses**

| ClassID | CrossID |
| --- | --- |
| EDU 103 | EDE 101 |
| EDE 101 | EDU 103 |

**Desired Output**

| QID | ClassID | TotalR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 21 | CMP 101 | 2 |
| 22 | EDU 103 | 3 |
| 23 | EDE 101 | 3 |

Answer (score 1):

There may be a better way to do this. But this is what I was able to come up with.

```
SELECT a.QID,a.CLASSID,count(a.rid) as totalR
from
(
SELECT distinct q.qid,q.classid,r.rid
from Question Q
left join CrossCourse cc on cc.CLASSID = q.CLASSID
left join Question Q2 on Q2.CLASSID = cc.CROSSID
left join Response R on q.qid = r.qid or q2.QID = r.qid
)a 
group by a.qid,a.classid
```

Essentially, we do the second join on Question Q2 so that we get the QID for the cross product name of the initial CLASSID. From there, we join on both QIDs to get the total response count.

SQL fiddle for context with the data and schema you provided:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4c4a60/10

Comment: Thank you for sharing this.
In the case of example, we did a left join on Q2.ClassID = cc.CrossID.

Would that work if there mere numerous other multiple class/cross combinations?

Comment: I'll try this on the SQL Server and get back to you.

Comment: Hmm my answer may not be scalable in that sense. Ive updated the query to essentially take the distinct response types for each question. There is a decent amount of assumptions that every CrossCourse option is in the table. 

If 101 has an alias of 103 and 105, but 103 doesnt have an alias of 105, there will be gaps.